# A rectification, what is the graph of the following?

Tags: graphing-functions

What is the graph of y=y(x) of:

$\sqrt {{{(x - 2)}^2} + {y^2}}  + \sqrt {{{(x + 2)}^2} + {y^2}}  + \sqrt {{x^2} + {{(y + 2)}^2}}  = 16$

Thank very much

Comment: from where does this problem come?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/124333/what-are-curves-generalized-ellipses-with-more-than-two-focal-points-called-an  and here: http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0702005v1.pdf