# What are these 3D shapes, if anything?

Tags: geometry

I'm trying to think of a 3D analogue to the ellipse, but **not** the ellipsoid.

A circle is constructed with a piece of string anchored at the radius. So the distance from center to the curve is always the same.

An ellipse is constructed with a piece of string ending at two foci. The sum of the two lines is always the same.

For 3D, I can think of 3 ways:

- Three points define a plane. These are our 3 foci. Make lines from each of them that meet at some point on the curve of the shape. **But the 3 lines must always sum to the same number.** (I'm pretty sure this is **not** and ellipsoid, but possibly, if 2 foci coincide, it would be an ellipsoid?)
- Three points define a plane. These are our 3 foci. Make lines from each of them that meet at some point on the curve of the shape. **This also defines a tetrahedon. The surface area of the tetrahedron must be constant.**
- Same as above, except we want the **volume** of the tetrahedron to be constant.

What do those shapes look like? Maybe someone knows how to program a 3D model, or graph it somehow? If so please post pictures.

Comment: Did you try using Geogebra? https://www.geogebra.org

Answer (score 4):

The set of points $M$ such that $MA+MB+MC=k$ in the case where $A=(0,0,0)$, $B=(1,0,0)$ and $C=(2,1,0)$ and $k=3.5$ to $6.5$ (with step $0.5$) look like this:

[image]

(points $A,B,C$ are materialized in blue).

Here is the Matlab program which has generated this figure:

```
      clear all;close all;axis equal;grid on
      Li=-4:0.1:4;L=length(Li);
      [X,Y,Z] = meshgrid(Li,Li,Li);
      V = sqrt(X.^2 + Y.^2 + Z.^2)+...
      sqrt((X-1).^2 + Y.^2 + Z.^2)+...
      sqrt(X.^2 + (Y+3).^2 + Z.^2);
      scatter3([0,1,0],[0,0,-3],[0,0,0],10,'b','filled');
      for k=3:0.5:6.5;
          p=patch(isosurface(X,Y,Z,V,k));
          set(p,'FaceColor','r','EdgeColor','none');lighting gouraud;
          alpha(0.1);
          view([112,18]);
          camlight right
      end
```

Comment: It looks kinda like a clam. Is there an official name for this shape? When I have time, I'll try to find a free demo of Matlab and learn how to use it for the other shapes.

Comment: Here is a reference with many pointers: (http://math.stackexchange.com/q/124333). They give the name "n-ellipse" to the curves; volumes are not mentionned. Another interesting reference: (https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~deloera/MISC/BIBLIOTECA/trunk/nellipse.pdf).

Comment: For a tetrahedron MABC with fixed points $A,B,C$, if you impose a constant volume for this tetrahedron, the locus of M will be a plane (or two planes) parallel to plane ABC because the volume of a tetrahedron is (1/3) area of triangle ABC $\times$ its height.

Comment: I see. Then I would hafta derive height from volume and base area. h = 3V/B. But yes this would be two parallel planes extending infinitely, so not a closed shape and not even a curved one. Fascinating.