# Do multi-focal-point hyperbolae exist?

Tags: geometry

I recently learned about k-ellipses (see [this other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/124333/what-are-curves-generalized-ellipses-with-more-than-two-focal-points-called-an)) and I wondered if there was such a thing about k-hyperbolae. I have seen the [Wikipedia article on 'Generalized Conics'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_conic), but I'm not able to discern their application to hyperbolae.

The question I have is what would hyperbolae with multiple focal points look like (if they even exist)? A picture of a 3-ellipse is given on Wikipedia's [N-ellipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-ellipse) page. I can imagine something akin to a 3-hyperbola being hyperbolas between any two of the vertices, but I'm not sure if that follows the generalized conic description.

An additional question is if they do exist, is there a literature on them?

Comment: Interesting question. You might define your generalization by requiring that the combination $d_1 + d_2 -d_3$ of distances to three foci be constant. You could try this for any number of foci and any combination of $\pm$ signs.

Comment: Yes, I figured it would be something like that. But I wasn’t sure how many sheets there would be. And before I tried to dig too deep. I wanted to know if there was already an existing literature for the concept and I just didn’t know the terminology.

Comment: In the plane these will be curves - perhaps weird. My guess is that there's no literature. There is information about weighted N-ellipses, but the weights on the distances to sum are all positive.